# How to use react-native-threads library

Tags: reactjs, multithreading, react-native

I went through [react-native-threads](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads) library and I was trying to figure out how to use it.

I can see they have two examples in [usage](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads#usage)

```
import { Thread } from 'react-native-threads';

// start a new react native JS process
const thread = new Thread('path/to/thread.js');

// send a message, strings only
thread.postMessage('hello');

// listen for messages
thread.onmessage = (message) => console.log(message);

// stop the JS process
thread.terminate();
```

and

```
import { self } from 'react-native-threads';

// listen for messages
self.onmessage = (message) => {
}

// send a message, strings only
self.postMessage('hello');
```

I couldn't understand the significance of `self` here? is it a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this solution https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-multithreading based on reanimated worklets.

```js
// JS thread
spawnThread(() => {
  'worklet'
  // custom thread
  // expensive calculation
})
// JS thread
```